# Looking for a Test of Quotients

Tags: hypothesis-testing

So I have roughly data from 8.000 persons: each person's working time and the time of absence from work due to illness.  What test should I use to determine whether there is a difference of the proportions
$$\text{absence quote}:=\frac{\text{absence time}}{\text{working time}}$$
in different groups, say men/women?

Edit: To clarify, I may be allowed to present the problem the I think I'm facing.  I'm just interested in the described quotient. I'm given 8000 person's data.

Assume in one group ($n_0 = 100$) the mean of *absence time* for a period, say a month, is 8h, in the other group ($n_1 = 300$) the mean is 17h.  The mean of  *working time* in the first group is 110h, in the second 150h.  Hence the quotient in the first group is $8/110$ whereas it's in the second $17/150$.  Now how to perform a test for the quotients?  (Sorry in case the question ist silly.)

First pic shows a box plot of *working time* ("Arbeitszeit"), the second on a box plot of *absence time* ("Ausfall").

Edit_2:  Following the advice I've plotted absence vs. work time an got something to think over:

[image]

But why should I take a square root scale?

Edit_3: I did a prtest for the proportion of people which absence time is more than 30% of their working time and got significant difference: 5.9% for group 0 and 12.8% for group 1.  Seems to me a much better strategy since the individual absence quotes are hardly comparable.

Thanks for your help again -- and any suggestions are welcome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First thing I'd do is to look at histogram/boxplot of ratios for men and women. I suppose data wouldn't be normal, but if sample distributions for men and women are similar in shape, I might try a two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test. // It would be helpful if you can show some plots of your data. I don't see how we can give a responsible answer with so little information from you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions; I've tried to clarify my problem.

Comment: Although you are interested in the proportions, the size of the denominator likely determines the uncertainty in the proportion.  An effective visual representation of the data would be a scatterplot of the numerator vs. the denominator.  The use of square-root scales on both axes would be a helpful beginning.  When you symbolize the points by group (such as gender), look for geometric clustering of *slopes* of fitted lines.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much, but I don't get your point.  I'm just interested whether the *absence quote* differs significantly in different groups.

Comment: The point is that when someone spends few hours at work, the absence quotient can be a much more variable indicator of their tendency to be absent compared to someone who spends many hours.  A correct statistical test therefore takes that into consideration.  When you examine only the ratios, you lose that crucial information.

Comment: Definitely true.  And there are much more factors as age, married or not, the time being employed, gender, income ...  Whatever, I'm "only" interested in the pairwise absence quotients.  OTOH would a regression be appropriate to take more than one effect into account?

Comment: IMHO, you should pay close attention to @whuber's Comments and suggestions--even (or especially) if that means re-thinking your goals.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested whether a *typical* absence quote (i.e. one that represents your data the best) significantly differs by gender, you can use the Yuen's t-test on 20% trimmed means (provided that no more than 20% of your dataset is comprised of outliers). In R this test can be conducted easily with the `yuen` function from the WRS2 package. Given your large sample size, the explanatory measure of effect size $\xi$ reported by this function will be also of particular importance. $\xi = 0.15, 0.30, 0.50$ translates roughly to small, medium respectively large effect size.

```
library(WRS2)

yuen(ratio ~ gender, yourdf)
```